# Removing an element from the DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$("#phoneR").find("input#phone").remove();
for (var i = 1; i <= para[3] - 1; i++) {
    $("#phoneR").find("td:eq(1)").after(" <input type='text' name='phone[]' disabled='disabled'/>");
}
```

The code above is suppose to iterate and add the input 3 times, but for some reasons what soever it's not doing. Is it that.

Am i doing something wrong.

@cyberomin

Comment: Did you check `para[3] - 1 > 1` ??

Comment: Is the problem with removing the original element or with adding the new ones?

Comment: Any error message you can see?

Comment: Adding a new element, the para[3] hold like 3 or 2 or 1 as their variable. How do i add the new element.

Comment: @Simon jquery Remove() removes the set of matched elements from the DOM - Ref http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Could you paste your html structure as well?

Comment: Your question doesn't **seem** to be about `remove()` as such...or am I badly misreading your question?

Comment: @Cyberomin At the moment, this question is impossible to answer. You need (a) to explain exactly what the problem is (i.e. what's going wrong and how) and (b) to show us your HTML.

Comment: agreed... Cyberomin, you're asking here "How do i add the new element" and to my answer you have commented: "My concern is how to remove the element...", so we're at a bit of loss as to what it's exactly that does not work in your code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the result of this?

```
$("#phoneR").find("td:eq(1)")
```

td:eq(1) retrieves the second td element that is found inside `$("#phoneR")`.  If you really want the first td, then you'll have to do:

```
 $("#phoneR").find("td:eq(0)")
```

Try to do `$("#phoneR").find("td:eq(1)").length` and make sure it equals 1.

Alternatively, you can use the :first selector, which is equivalent to :eq(0)

```
$("#phoneR").find("td:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling this would probably sound as a stupid question, but what's wrong with this approach?

```
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
```

I mean, if you want to add exactly 3 inputs, then **i < 3** would suffice

anyways, since you most probably will require the **para** variable, I would suggest caching it before going into the loop, as this would need to calculate **para[3] - 1** three times instead of one

```
var para_3 = para[3] - 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= para_3; i++)
```

Comment: disregard the first question, I just read the comments... the advice on using a cached variables remains, however

Comment: My concern is how to remove the element so that i can iterate and add new element in the DOM.